# How do I address an envelope where one person has a professional title but their spouse does not?

Tags: prefixes

When addressing an envelope to Dr John Smith and his wife, Jane Smith, what would be the proper form to utilize?  I have been using "Dr. and Mrs. John and Jane Smith", but I was told by my co-worker that it should really be "Dr. and Mrs John Smith".  Which, if either, is the correct format?

Comment: Not sure about what is correct but "Dr. and Mrs. John Smith" is my preference for reasons of brevity and crispness

Comment: For a formal invitation to both? Use the second. Consider [this](http://www.formsofaddress.info/Joint_Forms_of_Address.html#428) example too.

Comment: Not to kick the can down the road, but simply dropping all titles is supported by the US Post Office. Falling back on USPS solved my problem, which was how to send Christmas presents to a couple both of whom had doctorates. http://pe.usps.com/businessmail101/addressing/deliveryaddress.htm

Comment: Either is grammatically acceptable, so this is really more a question of etiquette and/or tradition. Please note that calling someone "Mrs [your husband's name]" could be offensive to some women - or even highly offensive to most women, depending on the cultural context. I would avoid it entirely and use "Dr John and Mrs Jane Smith", or, as per Elliot Frisch's link, "Dr and Mrs Smith".

Comment: @MichaelOwenSartin Yes two doctors in the same house can be difficult. But I have one instance of a Professor-Emeritus and his wife who is Dr to whom I send a Christmas card. I believe I settled for 'Professor and Dr Jones', last year and simply chickened out on the Christian name. Any ideas out there?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about etiquette rather than the English language

Answer (score 2):

*Dr and Mrs John and Jane Smith* is never going to be 'right', though it may pass muster: from a grammatical point of view it would have to be *Dr and Mrs John and Jane Smith respectively*, which is unlikely to catch on. Beyond that the question is a matter of the etiquette prevailing in your circle, about which you know more than any of us. There are those who still hold that calling a woman *Mrs Jane Smith* rather than *Mrs John Smith* implies that she is divorced or widowed; there are equally those who believe that anything but *Ms Jane Smith* (or preferably using her name at birth) implies that she is no feminist. *Dr and Mrs Smith* is acceptable in almost all situations; if you have to distinguish these Smiths from another couple, I suggest you consider what form has been used by other people.

Comment: Why would Mrs Jane Smith mean she is no longer married? If she took her husband's name, she is Mrs Smith regardless of what her first name is. Mrs John Smith could be considered offensive depending on the culture and tradition, as she has her own first name. And why is "Dr and Mrs John and Jane Smith" "never right"? I agree it's not the clearest, but I don't think it's "wrong".

Comment: @nxx: Early 20th century ladies were always *Mrs John Smith* as long as they were married, and *Mrs Jane Smith* was mildly insulting, as implying that she was divorced (shameful) or widowed (pitiable). We both said that this does not now usually apply, which is why it is a matter of etiquette rather than English. And *Dr and Mrs John and Jane Smith* is plainly worse than *Dr John and Mrs Jane Smith* because of the ambiguity, which can only be removed by adding *respectively*. The difference is probably not important, which is why 'wrong' is in inverted commas, and "it may pass muster".

Comment: Fair enough. I hold that "Dr and Mrs John and Jane Smith" is not ungrammatical, but I agree it is ambiguous. You said "There are those who still hold that calling a woman Mrs Jane Smith rather than Mrs John Smith implies..." I got that you were saying it's not necessarily a common belief now, but it seemed to me, at least, to be a little overstated. Out of interest, in your experience, *are* there really people who still hold that?

Comment: Certainly in my first job I was rebuked for addressing a formal letter that way; not because the lady would be insulted, but because she could be, and some people take any possible excuse to claim insult.  There still are people who care deeply about such things, though I would guess most of them are elderly.

Comment: You mean as "Mrs Jane Smith" rather than "Mrs John Smith"? That is interesting. I don't know of anyone under 40 that wouldn't be insulted to be called "Mrs John Smith'. On a side note, I also had someone tell me recently (whether or not this is true) that it's still acceptable to address a letter to an unknown recipient as "Dear Sir" in England. I guess some places are just more PC vs traditional than others.

Answer (score 0):

Do the contents of the envelope concern the professional specialty of the person who has earned the special honorific — in this case, Dr. John Smith? If so, then why would the spouse even be addressed? If not, there is nothing wrong with Dr. (or Mr.) and Mrs. John Smith. For less formality, omit even the common honorifics — e.g., Jane and John Smith. (In this case, being an old-fashioned sort, I lean toward leading with the lady's name.)